# Branch.io deeplink not working when open app first time

Tags: ios, branch.io

I'm trying to open my app and make a deeplink, but when I open by a link, the received params is without data, like when open the app without this link.

This only occurs when app is closed, if is opened and I click on the link, I get the expected params.

Anyone was faced this problem too?

Comment: Can you provide code for **func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool** function?

Comment: Thank you @Sergey, my code was returning the FBSDKApplicationDelegate and i don't have noticed this before.